# Somar valores do Select Multiple

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho o seguinte `select`:

```
<select name="idservico[]" id="idservico">
<option data-valor="25,00" value="1">opção 1</option>
<option data-valor="20,00" value="1">opção 2</option>
</select>
```

Tenho o seguinte `input`:

```
<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/>
```

Tenho o seguinte `script`:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#idservico').change(function() {

jQuery('#valor').val((jQuery(this).find(':selected').data('valor')));
    });
});
</script>
```

Então vamos lá, quando seleciono um serviço ele envia o valor do serviço para o `input`, mas preciso que quando selecionar outro serviço — porque meu `select` é múltiplo — ele teria que somar o valor do primeiro selecionado com o segundo.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Conseguir fazer até selecionar e enviar o valor para o `input`, mas somar nada até agora. Grato.

Comment: Veja se [isso te ajuda](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/5phtw2qx/).

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de somar os valores do `select` mantendo o formato dos valores com vírgula nas `options`:

### Com JavaScript puro

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
   document.querySelector("#idservico").addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
      let total = 0;
      for(let x of e.target.options){
         let val = parseFloat(x.dataset.valor.replace(',','.'));
         total += x.selected ? val : 0;
      }
      document.querySelector("#valor").value = total.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
   });
});
```

```html
<select name="idservico[]" id="idservico" multiple>
  <option data-valor="25,00" value="1">opção 1</option>
  <option data-valor="20,00" value="1">opção 2</option>
  <option data-valor="10,50" value="1">opção 3</option>
  <option data-valor="1250,50" value="1">opção 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/>
```

### Com jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#idservico").on("change",function(){
      let total = 0;
      for(let x of $(this)[0].options){
         let val = parseFloat($(x).data("valor").replace(',','.'));
         total += $(x).is(":selected") ? val : 0;
      }
      $("#valor").val(total.toFixed(2).replace('.',','));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="idservico[]" id="idservico" multiple>
  <option data-valor="25,00" value="1">opção 1</option>
  <option data-valor="20,00" value="1">opção 2</option>
  <option data-valor="10,50" value="1">opção 3</option>
  <option data-valor="1250,50" value="1">opção 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que dessa forma você não está somando, está apenas pegando o valor do `select` e adicionando no `input`.

Segue um exemplo que pode auxiliar.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('select[name="idservico[]"]').change(function() {

        let selects = jQuery("select[name=\"idservico[]\"]");
        let valorDoSelect = 0;
        
        /* Captura e soma o valor de todos os select */
        $(selects).map(function(i, e) {
          valorDoSelect += parseFloat( $(e).find(':selected').data('valor').toString().replace(",", ".") );
        });
    
        /* Exibe o valor */
        $('#valor').val( valorDoSelect )
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="idservico[]" id="idservico">
  <option data-valor="0" value="1">Selecione uma opção</option>
  <option data-valor="25,00" value="2">opção 1 (R$ 25,00)</option>
  <option data-valor="20,00" value="3">opção 2 (R$ 20,00)</option>
</select>

<select name="idservico[]" id="idservico2">
  <option data-valor="0" value="4">Selecione uma opção</option>
  <option data-valor="50,00" value="5">opção 3 (R$ 50,00)</option>
  <option data-valor="40,00" value="6">opção 4 (R$ 40,00)</option>
</select>


<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" readonly />
```

ou ainda

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('select[name="idservico[]"]').change(function() {

        let selects = jQuery("select[name=\"idservico[]\"]");
        let total = 0;
        
        /* Percorre todos os select */
        $(selects).map(function(i, e) {
          let values = $(e).find(":selected");
        
          /* Percorre todos os valores selecionados */
          $(values).map(function(k, j) {
            total += parseFloat( $(j).data('valor').replace(",", ".") );
          });
        });
        
        $("#valor").val(total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="idservico[]" id="idservico" multiple>
  <option data-valor="25,00" value="1">opção 1 (R$ 25,00)</option>
  <option data-valor="20,00" value="2">opção 2 (R$ 20,00)</option>
  <option data-valor="50,00" value="3">opção 3 (R$ 50,00)</option>
  <option data-valor="40,00" value="4">opção 4 (R$ 40,00)</option>
</select>

<select name="idservico[]" id="idservico" multiple>
  <option data-valor="1,00" value="1">opção 5 (R$ 1,00)</option>
  <option data-valor="2,00" value="2">opção 6 (R$ 2,00)</option>
  <option data-valor="3,00" value="3">opção 7 (R$ 3,00)</option>
  <option data-valor="4,00" value="4">opção 8 (R$ 4,00)</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" readonly />
```

> Quando você trabalha com moedas, evite utilizar vírgula (Ex: 25,00) para separar as casas decimais, utilize sempre pontos (Ex: 25.00).

Comment: Está somando o valor, mas se eu tirar um item da seleção ele soma também e não poderia.

Comment: @LucianoCoelhoPettersen alterei o código. Se possível dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#idservico').change(function() {
      var total = 0;
      $(this).find(':selected').each(function(i){
        total += parseFloat($(this).data('valor'));      
      });
      $('#valor').val(total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="idservico[]" id="idservico" multiple>
  <option data-valor="25.50" value="1">opção 1</option>
  <option data-valor="20.00" value="1">opção 2</option>
  <option data-valor="20.00" value="1">opção 3</option>
  <option data-valor="20.00" value="1">opção 4</option>
</select>
Tenho o seguinte input:
<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/>
Tenho o seguinte ajax:
```

Comment: este ficou perfeito, só que esta arredondando os centavos exemplo 25.50 + 30,00 está ficando 55,00

Comment: Você precisa substiuir as "," por "." pois é assim que o JavaScript reconhece decimais.

Comment: Correto, funcionou da forma que eu queria. Muito obrigado a todos. Boa tarde

Comment: Achei um outro problema, se o valor for 1.125,50 ele coloca o valor para 1.13 qual seria a forma correta de formatar?

Comment: Ou você adiciona os tratamentos para trabalhar com valores de moeda ou você utiliza o valor puro... no caso seria 1125.50

Comment: blz, entendi, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

o select fornece um array assim vc te que somar membro a membro do array
uma maneira simples seria assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("teste")
  $("select").change(function(){
    var soma = 0;
    $(this).find(":selected").each(function(id,element){
    console.log(element)
      soma = soma + parseFloat($(element).data("value"))
    })
    
    $("span").text(soma)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option data-value="50.00" value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option data-value="52.25" value="2">Saab</option>
  <option data-value="55.75" value="3">Opel</option>
  <option data-value="58.00" value="5">Audi</option>
</select>
<p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>

<p>soma = <span></span></p>

</form>
```

go aqui

Comment: Este esta somando o valeu e não a data que contém os valores

Comment: @LucianoCoelhoPettersen editei e coloquei para pegar o data